# pandas to_csv using latin script Ç as separator?

Tags: python, pandas

My team uses a Ç (ALT 0199) as a separator in their CSV files.  I'm trying to replicate using this in Pandas, but not having any luck.  Any guidance is appreciated as I'm new to Pandas

```
results.to_csv('filename.csv', encoding='latin1', sep='Ç')
```

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' can't decode byte 0xc7

Comment: try to use `encoding='iso-8859-1'` or `encoding='cp1252'` instead of `encoding='latin1'`

Comment: @shreydeshwal I still get the same syntax error regardless of the encoding parameter value.  Not sure that the encoding parameter applies to the delimiter used.

Comment: but....... why?

Comment: Why `latin1` or *anything* other than UTF8? In Python 3 strings are Unicode only. The [default source code encoding](https://peps.python.org/pep-3120/) is UTF8 too.

Comment: In fact, you're lucky Python crashed. If you try to use the wrong single-byte encoding you'll end up with *different* characters than those you thought you were using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you get a SyntaxError seems to indicate that Python can’t even read your program, let alone run it. It would seem that your Python source code file is encoded as iso-8859-1 (a.k.a latin-1), but Python thinks it’s in the default utf-8 encoding. Try adding a comment at the beginning of the file:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
```

See [the Lexical Analysis chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations) of the language reference for details.

Alternatively, avoid using "funny" characters in the source code, and do

```
results.to_csv(blabla, sep='\u00c7')
```

(And seriously, if you need to use funny separators in your "C"SV:s, then something, somewhere, isn’t using a proper CSV parser. Chaos awaits in your future...)

Comment: The *real* solution is to save the source as UTF8, which is [the default source code encoding](https://peps.python.org/pep-3120/) Anything else just begs for errors at best or misinterpreted data in the worst case. At least with a crash, you *know* something is wrong

Comment: Thank you @ture-pålsson!  Swapping out the funny character as you show above worked, even without specifying the coding.

Comment: @SoupGyro Yes, I realized, after writing, that keeping the source code to ASCII-only and using an explicit unicode escape is probably a better idea than to declare the source code as latin-1. I sort of agree with Panagiotis Kanavos’ comment, but go one step further — don’t even use utf-8, use ASCII!

Answer (score 0):

for me it seems to work in python3.10 and pandas2.0.3:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
df.to_csv('test_1111111111.csv',sep='Ç')
```

when i look at the file test_1111111111.csv I see:

```
Ç0Ç1Ç2Ç3
0Ç0Ç0Ç0Ç0
1Ç0Ç0Ç0Ç0
2Ç0Ç0Ç0Ç0
```

I think this is what you want.